# Groovy shell script doesn't recognize aws command

Tags: macos, groovy, groovyshell

I have a groovy script like this:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    println('Hello World');
    String command = """aws s3 ls"""
    println(command.execute().text)
}
```

When I run `groovy file.groovy`, it outputs:

```
Hello World
Caught: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "aws": error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "aws": error=2, No such file or directory
    at com.capitalone.cep.lensOps.run(lensOps.groovy:11)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    ... 1 more
```

That shell command works fine in bash but not through the groovy script. I wasn't even able to run `source ~/.bash_profile` in groovy shell. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: I've just checked it and it works fine for me - macos as well. Also, maybe this answer will be of any help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269494/why-cant-groovy-find-this-program-even-though-its-on-my-path

Comment: Problems with environment variables. Ihmo